# Javascript: Find index of slash (/) in a string

Tags: javascript

I don't know much about javascript (only done JAVA) but that havent keept me from doing a hack on some javascript code I found (from Google Bookmarks).

Here is my case: I'm creating a bookmark in my browser that contains a javascript instead of a URL link. When I press the bookmark I want it to open a new window with the same url but with some extra info.
So say Im on https://www.abcde.com/KnowYourABC and I press the bookmark, then it should open a window with the link: https://www.abcde.com.DoYou/KnowYourABC - so ".DoYou" have been inserted just before the 3th "/"

I have the following script:

```
javascript:(function(){
    var a=window, b=document, c=encodeURIComponent,
    url = b.location,
    d = a.open(url, "bkmk_popup", "left="+
    ((a.screenX||a.screenLeft)+50)+",top="+
    ((a.screenY||a.screenTop)+50)+
    ",height=600px, width=1200px, resizable=1, alwaysRaised=1");
    a.setTimeout(function(){d.focus()},300)
})();
```

So far it opens a window with the same url. But I can't seem to split the url at the 3th "/". Have tried to get the index of the backslash in order to split the url and insert ".DoYou"

```
 i = url.indexOf("//",9)
```

but then the window will not open. Please help me out!

**SOLUTION**

```
javascript:( function(){ 
    var a=window;
    b=document;
    c=encodeURIComponent; 
    url = b.location; 
    var parts = window.location.href.split("/");
    parts[2] += ".DoYou";
    var newurl = parts.join("/");
    a.open(newurl, "bkmk_popup","left="+((a.screenX||a.screenLeft)+50)+",top="+((a.screenY||a.screenTop)+50)+",height=600px,width=1200px,resizable=1,alwaysRaised=1"); a.setTimeout(function(){d.focus()},300);
})();
```

Comment: You might want to post un-minified javascript code.

Comment: For reference, `/` is a regular slash. `\\` is a backslash.

Comment: `/` only needs to be escaped in regexpes, where is becomes ``\/``. In strings `/` is sufficient (it doesn't clash with anything).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done with a simple reg exp, using the parts of the window.location object [host/search/etc] or a simple split and join.

Here is the simple split and join solution.

```
var parts = window.location.href.split("/");
parts[2] += ".DOYOU";
var newStr = parts.join("/");
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: This makes much sense! Thank you your help!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to escape the `/` (forward slash).

```
i = url.indexOf("/",9)
```

P.S. The escape character is usually a backslash (`\`).

Comment: @Norfeldt: What do you mean by "does not work".  `"https://www.abcde.com/KnowYourABC".indexOf("/", 9) === 21`

Comment: It does not work. Try to make a bookmak in your browser (I use chrome) with this code and you will see that it will not open javascript:( function(){ var a=window,b=document,c=encodeURIComponent, url = b.location, i = url.indexOf("/",9), d=a.open(url, "bkmk_popup","left="+((a.screenX||a.screenLeft)+50)+",top="+((a.screenY||a.screenTop)+50)+",height=600px,width=1200px,resizable=1,alwaysRaised=1"); a.setTimeout(function(){d.focus()},300)})();

Comment: I assume that it does not open because the index method does not work

Comment: I'm well aware that I don't split the String. But having the index in place should not block the rest of the code to not being performed. If it then opened the site as normal then I would split it.

Comment: @Norfeldt: The issue is not with the `indexOf` line, the issue is there is an "illegal" character in the `d=a.open` line.  There's some odd character in `url=",top=" + ((a.screenY || a.scree‌nTop) + 50);`.

Comment: @Norfeldt: There's a hidden character between the `e` and `n` in `a.screenTop`.  Hex code `1F`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8540/discussion-between-norfeldt-and-rocket)

Answer (score 0):

In a similar way to the accepted answer, if you don't really need to find the index, but want to place something near it, you can use `string.replace(replacedtext, newtext)` and RegEx.

For your URL example, if you wanted to add text before the first slash with word characters on either side, you could do

```
url = url.replace(/(\w(?=\/\w))/, '$1' + '.DoYou');
```

The `$1` inserts the 1st parenthesized submatch string (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) for more explanation of the `$`).

**Example**

Like your issue, I wanted to do the same thing except in the same window, so I did:

```
javascript:void(location.href=location.href.replace(/(\w(?=\/\w))/,'$1'+'.DoYou'))
```

Having this as a bookmark allows me to just click the bookmark and take me to the page I want.