# Javascript: Replace string in current url?

Tags: javascript, window.location

I looking for a script that will detect the current url and amend the current url.  Example:

find: http://example.php and replace with http://example-newstring.php

I can currently find the url replace the url using window.location but I'm stuck on how to replace the .php with new characters.

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What techniques have you tried up to this point?  Can you show some of your code that you already have to help us see what else you might need?

Comment: Could you show more examples? Before/after, in addition to what you've tried so far?

Comment: You **do** know that *amending* the current url will redirect you to that page .. *right ?* (*unless you mean inside links*)

Comment: Not necessarily, if you use the HTML5 history API it doesn't.

Comment: @Magrangs, good point (*although, the OP mentions `window.location` in the tags, and also the example alters the domain which is not possible with history API*).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Find index of slash (/) in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568017/javascript-find-index-of-slash-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Try `window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(".php", "-newstring.php");`

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 history API

```
try {
  window.history.pushState({}, "Alternate title", host);
} catch (e) {}
```

DOES NOT WORK IN IE 7-9

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a HTML 5 compliant browser you can use the history api.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history